# how to make UI controls appear properly in a dialog box

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I want to collect user input from a dialog box caller alert1.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert1=new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
LinearLayout layout1=new LinearLayout(context);//context is an object of type Context previously initialised to 'this'
layout1.addView(box1);//box1 is an EditText
alert1.setView(layout1);
alert1.show();
```

this however makes the edittext appear reallys small. but if i do this instead

```
alert1.setView(box1);
```

and get rid of the LinearLayout all together it appears right but i cant add anymore custom ui controls to this alert box. Can someone tell me where i'm wrong

its for target android 4.0

also i tried both orientations for the linear layout..

Comment: Can you show us your layout file ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `LayoutParams` in the `LinearLayout` with the following code  `linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);`.